# [BATCH / .Bat files]Help Toggling some option menus / toggle-able menus

Tags: batch-file

Another question about batch files

i know how choice works (also choice.com) but once in the back ive seen an option menu that would let you to toggle between options

like 
`something [ON] OFF` and when toggled `something ON [OFF]` vice versa

i know 2 ways ..

```
which 1 way is to write both conditions and display the one needed ..
and the other is to toggle "[  ]" signs ...
```

**i cant do the 2nd way and need some help.**.
also ive been looking at movement articles but they do not seem to have anything to help

thx for reading the passage and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably dozens of ways to accomplish this.  Here is one simple way, likely not the most elegant but it works:

```
@echo off

set _on=0

:top
cls

if %_on%==0 (set _nlb= &set _nrb= &set _flb=[&set _frb=]) else (set _nlb=[&set _nrb=]&set _flb= &set _frb= )

echo The '_on' flag is currently: %_nlb% On %_nrb%  %_flb% Off %_frb%
echo.
echo Press any key to toggle the '_on' flag
pause>nul

if %_on%==0 (set _on=1) else (set _on=0)
goto top
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :D i found another way / integrated some errorlevel codes
now looks more better :D